# Generating all possibilities with letters in python and exploiting results in python3

Tags: python

First, I got this problem: how many words are there (counting all of them, even  those that don't make sense) of 5 letters that have at least one I and at least two T's, but no K or Y?

First, I defined the alphabet, which has 24 letters ( k and y aren't counted). After that, i made a code to generate all possibilites

```
alphabet = list(range(1, 24))
for L in range(0, len(alphabet)+1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(alphabet, L):
```

I don't know how to use the data.

Comment: "First, i defined the alphabet, which has 24 letters"—Where did you do that?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the mathematical answer would be `24!/4!`. You can simply use this formula (permutation formula)

Comment: You need `range(1, 25)` if you want the numbers from 1 to 24 inclusive.

Comment: I'm in the middle of a combinatorics class myself right now. This (the "brute force" method) is _not_ how you're supposed to come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If a “brute force” method is enough for you, this will work:

```
import string
import itertools

alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase.replace("K", "").replace("Y", "")

count = 0
for word in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat = 5):
    if "I" in word and word.count("T") >= 2:
        count += 1

print (count)
```

It will print the result 15645.

Note that you have to use `itertools.product()`, because `itertools.permutations()` will not contain repeated occurences, so it will never contain “T” twice.

*Edit:* Alternatively, you can calculate the count with a list comprehension or a generator expression. It takes advantage of the fact that boolean `True` and `False` are equivalent to integer values 1 and 0, respectively.

```
count = sum(
    "I" in word and word.count("T") >= 2
    for word in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat = 5)
)
```

NB: Interestingly, the first solution (explicit `for` loop with `counter += 1`) runs about 15 % faster on my computer than the second solution (generator expression with `sum()`). Both require the same amount of memory (this is expected).